# Eevee white looks grey

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, color

I am trying to render a blenderkit scene in eevee but the white pump on the bottle looks grey. The scene was originally created in cycles. Comparison pics:

EEVEE

[image]

CYCLES

[image]

Plastic shader node:

[image]

Render with Sergey's solution:

[image]

Blender v: 3.4

Comment: I guess it might have to do with the transparent cap since _Cycles_ and _Eevee_ handle transparency differently.

Comment: I have added the node setup for the material.

Comment: Maybe it's the default Filmic Color transformation? Check `Render Properties > Color Management > View Transform` and set it to `Standard` if it's set to anything else

Comment: Sergey, that works too, but it made everything in the scene very saturated with a warm tone. Added render image.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to duplicate the rectangular area light in front of the scene, rotate and push to the back of the scene to light the transparent cap from behind.